# Simplificar jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

espero puedan ayudarme a como se debe de simplificar algunas acciones en jquery. Este esmi ejemplo https://codepen.io/critter236/pen/NEVgPW.

Hace lo que quiero, pero creo que se puede simplificar, pensaría que es lo correcto.

Del ejemplo que puse esta seria la parte :

```
$("#div-prueba-1").on('click', function () {
        $("#div-prueba-1").toggleClass("show");
        $("#div-prueba-2").toggleClass("hide");
        $("#div-prueba-3").toggleClass("hide");
        $("#div-prueba-4").toggleClass("hide");
    });
    $("#div-prueba-2").on('click', function () {
        $("#div-prueba-2").toggleClass("show");
        $("#div-prueba-1").toggleClass("hide");
        $("#div-prueba-3").toggleClass("hide");
        $("#div-prueba-4").toggleClass("hide");
    });
    $("#div-prueba-3").on('click', function () {
        $("#div-prueba-3").toggleClass("show");
        $("#div-prueba-1").toggleClass("hide");
        $("#div-prueba-2").toggleClass("hide");
        $("#div-prueba-4").toggleClass("hide");
    });
    $("#div-prueba-4").on('click', function () {
        $("#div-prueba-4").toggleClass("show");
        $("#div-prueba-1").toggleClass("hide");
        $("#div-prueba-2").toggleClass("hide");
        $("#div-prueba-3").toggleClass("hide");
    });
```

---

```js
$("#div-prueba-1").on('click', function() {
  $("#div-prueba-1").toggleClass("show");
  $("#div-prueba-2").toggleClass("hide");
  $("#div-prueba-3").toggleClass("hide");
  $("#div-prueba-4").toggleClass("hide");
});
$("#div-prueba-2").on('click', function() {
  $("#div-prueba-2").toggleClass("show");
  $("#div-prueba-1").toggleClass("hide");
  $("#div-prueba-3").toggleClass("hide");
  $("#div-prueba-4").toggleClass("hide");
});
$("#div-prueba-3").on('click', function() {
  $("#div-prueba-3").toggleClass("show");
  $("#div-prueba-1").toggleClass("hide");
  $("#div-prueba-2").toggleClass("hide");
  $("#div-prueba-4").toggleClass("hide");
});
$("#div-prueba-4").on('click', function() {
  $("#div-prueba-4").toggleClass("show");
  $("#div-prueba-1").toggleClass("hide");
  $("#div-prueba-2").toggleClass("hide");
  $("#div-prueba-3").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.box-general {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.box-general .box-cont {
  transition: all 0.6s linear;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box-general .box-cont.show {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.box-general .box-cont.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.box-general>div:first-child {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  left: 0;
}

.box-general>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #999999;
  left: 25%;
}

.box-general>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #666666;
  left: 50%;
}

.box-general>div:last-child {
  background-color: #333333;
  left: 75%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-general">
  <div id="div-prueba-1" class="box-cont">
    <div class="box-display"></div>
    <div class="cont-inter">
      Contenido
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div-prueba-2" class="box-cont">
    perro 2
  </div>
  <div id="div-prueba-3" class="box-cont">
    perro 3
  </div>
  <div id="div-prueba-4" class="box-cont">
    perro 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deberias de copiar tu codigo aqui.  Ademas especifica que es lo que quieres simplificar.

Comment: La idea es simplificar la parte que hace que se muestre cada elemento y esconda a los demas.

Comment: el ícono de `[<>]` es casi como codepen, ahí te lo incluí

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando la clase en vez del ID, mostrar el del click y ocultando los hermanos

```js
$(".box-cont").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("show");
  $(this).siblings().toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.box-general {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.box-general .box-cont {
  transition: all 0.6s linear;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box-general .box-cont.show {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.box-general .box-cont.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.box-general>div:first-child {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  left: 0;
}

.box-general>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #999999;
  left: 25%;
}

.box-general>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #666666;
  left: 50%;
}

.box-general>div:last-child {
  background-color: #333333;
  left: 75%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-general">
  <div id="div-prueba-1" class="box-cont">
    <div class="box-display"></div>
    <div class="cont-inter">
      Contenido
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div-prueba-2" class="box-cont">
    perro 2
  </div>
  <div id="div-prueba-3" class="box-cont">
    perro 3
  </div>
  <div id="div-prueba-4" class="box-cont">
    perro 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta solo reduciría/optimizaría el código a una linea aprovechando que ambas lineas crean un objeto `jQuery` a partir de `this` quedando asi: `$(this).toggleClass("show").siblings().toggleClass("hide");`

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo que le pongas una clase a todos tus elementos. Llamemosla : "clase_divs"

Si juegas simplemente con el hecho de que si no tienen la clase "hide" se entiende que no estan ocultos, podrías simplificarlo aún mas:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clase_divs").on('click', function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var num = id.substr(id.length - 1);
      $(".clase_divs").addClass("hide");
      $("#div-prueba-"+num).removeClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}

.clase_divs{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clase_divs" id="div-prueba-1">div 1</div>
<div class="clase_divs" id="div-prueba-2">div 2</div>
<div class="clase_divs" id="div-prueba-3">div 3</div>
<div class="clase_divs" id="div-prueba-4">div 4</div>
```

Y si juegas con el método filter:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clase_divs").on('click', function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var num = id.substr(id.length - 1);
      $(".clase_divs").addClass("hide").filter(function(){
       return $(this).attr('id') == 'div-prueba-'+num;
      }).removeClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}

.clase_divs{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clase_divs" id="div-prueba-1">div 1</div>
<div class="clase_divs" id="div-prueba-2">div 2</div>
<div class="clase_divs" id="div-prueba-3">div 3</div>
<div class="clase_divs" id="div-prueba-4">div 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Que te parece esta reducción?

```
    $("#div-prueba-1").on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("show");
        $("#div-prueba-2, #div-prueba-3, #div-prueba-4").toggleClass("hide");
    });
    $("#div-prueba-2").on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("show");
        $("#div-prueba-1, #div-prueba-3, #div-prueba-4").toggleClass("hide");
    });
    $("#div-prueba-3").on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("show");
        $("#div-prueba-1, #div-prueba-2, #div-prueba-4").toggleClass("hide");
    });
    $("#div-prueba-4").on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("show");
        $("#div-prueba-1, #div-prueba-2, #div-prueba-3").toggleClass("hide");
    });
```

Comment: Orale , muchas gracias, támbien me gusto esta respuesta. Saludos